# make edit button view only assisiate associate edit div?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have problem with ngClick toggleEdit item.when user click edit item will open all edit divs that have same index for example if item 1 in first div it will open all first item on 2nd and 3rd divs. I have create this  jsfiddle to illustrate the problem http://jsfiddle.net/u217rsmd/4/#&togetherjs=ToCzE84Tj7

```
 angular.module('demoApp', [])
        .controller('mainController', function ($scope) {
        $scope.editingMode = [];
        $scope.backup = [];

        $scope.model = {
            rrnConditionsValues: [{
                formControllerValueName: "a"
            }, {
                formControllerValueName: "b"
            }, {
                formControllerValueName: "c"
            }, {
                formControllerValueName: "d"
            }],
                 rrnConditionsValues2: [{
                formControllerValueName: "e"
            }, {
                formControllerValueName: "f"
            }, {
                formControllerValueName: "g"
            }, {
                formControllerValueName: "h"
            }],
              rrnConditionsValues3: [{
                formControllerValueName: "r"
            }, {
                formControllerValueName: "t"
            }, {
                formControllerValueName: "k"
            }, {
                formControllerValueName: "l"
            }],
        };

        $scope.updateValue = function (value, index) {
            //itemsManagementService.updateValue(value); // just removed for the demo
            $scope.editingMode[index] = false;
        };

        $scope.cancel = function (index) {
            $scope.model.rrnConditionsValues[index].formControllerValueName
                = $scope.backup[index];
            $scope.editingMode[index] = false;
        };

        $scope.toggleEdit = function (index) {
            // save current model value so we can restore it on cancel
            $scope.backup[index] = $scope.model.rrnConditionsValues[index].formControllerValueName;
            console.log($scope.backup);
            $scope.editingMode[index] = !$scope.editingMode[index];
            //$scope.selected = model;
        };

        $scope.deleteValue = function(index) {
            $scope.model.rrnConditionsValues.splice(index,1);
        };
    });
```

html

```
<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="mainController">
    <ul>
        <li data-ng-repeat="value in model.rrnConditionsValues">
            <div id="showItem" data-ng-show="!editingMode[$index]">
                <input class="" type="submit" value="Edit" data-ng-click="toggleEdit($index)">
                <input class="" type="submit" value="Delete" data-ng-click="deleteValue($index)">
                <label>{{value.formControllerValueName}}</label>
            </div>
            <div id="editItem" data-ng-show="editingMode[$index]">
                <input class="" type="submit" value="update" data-ng-click="updateValue(value, $index)">
                <input class="" type="submit" value="Cancel" data-ng-click="cancel($index)">
                <input type="text" size="30" data-ng-model="value.formControllerValueName" placeholder="add new  here">
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
     <ul>
        <li data-ng-repeat="value in model.rrnConditionsValues2">
            <div id="showItem" data-ng-show="!editingMode[$index]">
                <input class="" type="submit" value="Edit" data-ng-click="toggleEdit($index)">
                <input class="" type="submit" value="Delete" data-ng-click="deleteValue($index)">
                <label>{{value.formControllerValueName}}</label>
            </div>
            <div id="editItem" data-ng-show="editingMode[$index]">
                <input class="" type="submit" value="update" data-ng-click="updateValue(value, $index)">
                <input class="" type="submit" value="Cancel" data-ng-click="cancel($index)">
                <input type="text" size="30" data-ng-model="value.formControllerValueName" placeholder="add new  here">
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
                <ul>
        <li data-ng-repeat="value in model.rrnConditionsValues3">
            <div id="showItem" data-ng-show="!editingMode[$index]">
                <input class="" type="submit" value="Edit" data-ng-click="toggleEdit($index)">
                <input class="" type="submit" value="Delete" data-ng-click="deleteValue($index)">
                <label>{{value.formControllerValueName}}</label>
            </div>
            <div id="editItem" data-ng-show="editingMode[$index]">
                <input class="" type="submit" value="update" data-ng-click="updateValue(value, $index)">
                <input class="" type="submit" value="Cancel" data-ng-click="cancel($index)">
                <input type="text" size="30" data-ng-model="value.formControllerValueName" placeholder="add new  here">
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: did you see jsfiddle ?

Comment: @Pete I updated fiddle code

Comment: see my solution. I answered only your question but your code still needs some modifications to work properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets focus on the toggleEdit method. How could this method separate between different calls? sending the `index` only as a parameter doesn't do this. You need the `index` variable to select which `<li>` should have the edit mode but you also need another variable to select which `<ul>` should be affected.
You need to find a way to do that. I can suggest a very hard coded way just for illustrating the problem and inspiring you for a better solution:
replace `$scope.editingMode = [];` with :

```
$scope.editingMode[] = [];
$scope.editingMode[1] = [];
$scope.editingMode[2] = [];
$scope.editingMode[3] = [];
```

replace each one of `data-ng-click="toggleEdit($index)"` with the following respectivily

```
data-ng-click="toggleEdit($index,0)"
data-ng-click="toggleEdit($index,1)"
data-ng-click="toggleEdit($index,2)"
```

replace each one of `data-ng-click="!toggleEdit($index)"` with the following respectivily

```
data-ng-click="!toggleEdit($index,0)"
data-ng-click="!toggleEdit($index,1)"
data-ng-click="!toggleEdit($index,2)"
```

replace

```
$scope.editingMode[index] = !$scope.editingMode[index];
```

with

```
$scope.editingMode[x][index] = !$scope.editingMode[x][index];
```

see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hzq84o2h/3/)

Full code here (adding cancel functionality):

```
<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="mainController">
    <ul>
        <li data-ng-repeat="value in model.rrnConditionsValues">
            <div id="showItem" data-ng-show="!editingMode[0][$index]">
                <input class="" type="submit" value="Edit" data-ng-click="toggleEdit($index,0)">
                <input class="" type="submit" value="Delete" data-ng-click="deleteValue($index)">
                <label>{{value.formControllerValueName}}</label>
            </div>
            <div id="editItem" data-ng-show="editingMode[0][$index]">
                <input class="" type="submit" value="update" data-ng-click="updateValue(value, $index)">
                <input class="" type="submit" value="Cancel" data-ng-click="cancel($index,0)">
                <input type="text" size="30" data-ng-model="value.formControllerValueName" placeholder="add new  here">
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
     <ul>
        <li data-ng-repeat="value in model.rrnConditionsValues2">
            <div id="showItem" data-ng-show="!editingMode[1][$index]">
                <input class="" type="submit" value="Edit" data-ng-click="toggleEdit($index,1)">
                <input class="" type="submit" value="Delete" data-ng-click="deleteValue($index)">
                <label>{{value.formControllerValueName}}</label>
            </div>
            <div id="editItem" data-ng-show="editingMode[1][$index]">
                <input class="" type="submit" value="update" data-ng-click="updateValue(value, $index)">
                <input class="" type="submit" value="Cancel" data-ng-click="cancel($index,1)">
                <input type="text" size="30" data-ng-model="value.formControllerValueName" placeholder="add new  here">
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
                <ul>
        <li data-ng-repeat="value in model.rrnConditionsValues3">
            <div id="showItem" data-ng-show="!editingMode[2][$index]">
                <input class="" type="submit" value="Edit" data-ng-click="toggleEdit($index,2)">
                <input class="" type="submit" value="Delete" data-ng-click="deleteValue($index)">
                <label>{{value.formControllerValueName}}</label>
            </div>
            <div id="editItem" data-ng-show="editingMode[2][$index]">
                <input class="" type="submit" value="update" data-ng-click="updateValue(value, $index)">
                <input class="" type="submit" value="Cancel" data-ng-click="cancel($index,2)">
                <input type="text" size="30" data-ng-model="value.formControllerValueName" placeholder="add new  here">
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Script part:

```
 angular.module('demoApp', [])
        .controller('mainController', function ($scope) {
        $scope.editingMode = [];
        $scope.editingMode[0] = [];
        $scope.editingMode[1] = [];
        $scope.editingMode[2] = [];
        $scope.backup = [];

        $scope.model = {
            rrnConditionsValues: [{
                formControllerValueName: "a"
            }, {
                formControllerValueName: "b"
            }, {
                formControllerValueName: "c"
            }, {
                formControllerValueName: "d"
            }],
                 rrnConditionsValues2: [{
                formControllerValueName: "e"
            }, {
                formControllerValueName: "f"
            }, {
                formControllerValueName: "g"
            }, {
                formControllerValueName: "h"
            }],
              rrnConditionsValues3: [{
                formControllerValueName: "r"
            }, {
                formControllerValueName: "t"
            }, {
                formControllerValueName: "k"
            }, {
                formControllerValueName: "l"
            }],
        };

        $scope.updateValue = function (value, index) {
            //itemsManagementService.updateValue(value); // just removed for the demo
            $scope.editingMode[index] = false;
        };

        $scope.cancel = function (index,x) {
            $scope.model.rrnConditionsValues[index].formControllerValueName
                = $scope.backup[index];
            $scope.editingMode[x][index] = false;
        };

        $scope.toggleEdit = function (index,x) {
            // save current model value so we can restore it on cancel
            $scope.backup[index] = $scope.model.rrnConditionsValues[index].formControllerValueName;
            console.log($scope.backup);
            $scope.editingMode[x][index] = !$scope.editingMode[x][index];
            //$scope.selected = model;
        };

        $scope.deleteValue = function(index) {
            $scope.model.rrnConditionsValues.splice(index,1);
        };
    });
```

Comment: I found bug on you fiddle if you click edit  on 2nd div it will delete the items

Comment: but as I said, this code to illustrate the problem and helping you implement a good dynamic solution. my edits will add some functionalities related to your question but also will affect others.

Comment: this is the working one https://jsfiddle.net/hzq84o2h/2/ .. i edited the answer and corrected the link

Comment: and here is another fiddle correcting the functionality of he cancel button https://jsfiddle.net/hzq84o2h/3/